Final element of a hereditary set?
As I know from wikipedia, ZFC is about the study of pure (or hereditary set). A hereditary set is a set whose elements are themselves sets.
Ref: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory
In the meantime, there is the axiom of regularity which prevents having infinite descending chain. With respect to the relation $\in$, I understand it means that given a set $A$, there is a "set" $x$ such that $x \in x_1 \in x_2 \in.. \in A$ and there isn't a set $y$ such that $y \in x$. In this case, $x$ isn't a hereditary set because there isn't anything inside $x$, which contradicts what is said in Wikipedia that ZFC only considers hereditary sets. I'm confused.
Could you please tell me if ZFC is really about hereditary sets ? In ZFC,  can I understand from the axiom of regularity that there are indeed "something" $x$ which has no element ? Thank you all!

One thing you might want to look up would be "urelements" or "atoms." These are non-sets that can be elements of sets, but have no elements, themselves. Their existence requires that Regularity fail to hold, if I recall correctly.

"A hereditary set is a set whose elements are themselves sets."  OK...  The empty set is hereditary... is that your question?  in ZF, that is the only set with no elements.

@GEdgar: The empty set is hereditary because it is vacuous. But what I would like to ask is that it seems to me hereditary set and well-foundedness couldn't exist at the same time, but Wikipedia claims that set theory considers only hereditary set while being well-founded, which confused me...

This part is wrong: "In this case, $x$ isn't a hereditary set because there isn't anything inside $x$".

The Axiom of Regularity is: ∀x[ ∃y(y∈x) ⇒ ∃w(w∈x ∧ ¬∃z(z∈x ∧ z∈w)]
Less Formally,
∀x[ x ≠ ∅ ⇒ ∃w(w∈x ∧ x ∩ w = ∅)]
In English: All nonempty sets are disjoint from one of their elements.
I suspect your confusion is that you are not aware that the axiom of Foundation is only saying that non-empty sets are disjoint from one of their elements.
It might be useful to see two application of Foundation, to understand how the Axiom Works.
Application 1:  ¬∃x(x∈x)
Proof
(RAA) Assume otherwise, so pick x s.t. x∈x.
Consider {x}. This is a nonempty set, so by the Axiom of Foundation, it is disjoint from one of its elements.
It's only element is x, So it must be the case that {x} ∩ x = ∅
but x is in both sets. Contradiction. Thus, there is no set which is an element of itself.
Application 2: There is no infinite ∈-descending chains.
Proof
Assume we have a sequence <$x_n$|n$\in$ℕ> s.t. for n<m, $x_m$∈$x_n$
Applying the axiom of foundation to range(<$x_n$|n$\in$ℕ>) = {$x_n$|n$\in$ℕ}
for some $x_i$$\in${$x_n$|n$\in$ℕ}, $x_i$ ∩ {$x_n$|n$\in$ℕ} = ∅
but $x_{i+1}$$\in$$x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$$\in${$x_n$|n$\in$ℕ}
Contradiction.

The Axiom of Regularity states that for any set $a,$ if $a$ is non-empty, then there is some $x\in a$ such that $a\cap x=\emptyset.$ This doesn't necessarily mean that $x$ has no elements, although it certainly can happen--consider the set $\{\emptyset\}.$
As a consequence of $\mathsf{ZF},$ we can show that if $a$ is a non-empty set, then there is no sequence $\langle x_n\rangle_{n\in\omega}$ of elements $x_n\in a$ such that $x_{n+1}\in x_n$ for all $n\in\omega.$ (Note: This is reversed from what your post states, and seems like it may be the source of your confusion.) We might call such a sequence "$\in$-decreasing." If the Principle of Countable Dependent Choices holds, then we can prove the usual Axiom of Regularity from the "no $\in$-decreasing sequences" result.
However, we can have sequences that go the other way. For instance, the set $\omega$ of finite ordinals gives an example of a set that has sequences $\langle x_n\rangle_{n\in\omega}$ of elements such that $x_n\in x_{n+1}$ for all $n\in\omega.$

Hello, thanks for your response! So what is the role of "hereditary set" in this case ? Can you explain me a little bit more ? Because it seems to me that hereditary set (which has sets whose are sets themselves) contradicts what is said in the axiom of regularity.

A set whose elements are all sets need not be a hereditary set. Rather, a hereditary set is a set whose elements are all hereditary sets. This definition would be circular, but the Axiom of Regularity not only makes it well-defined (by preventing infinite descent), but actually allows us to prove that every set is hereditary. (For more information, look up the cumulative heirarchy of the von Neumann universe.) Out of curiosity, what about the Axiom of Regularity suggests a contradiction with the idea of hereditary sets?
